# How to append url to the end of a button link in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming I am currently on the page:

```
www.mysite.com/root/#/?page=orderpage
```

On the page, I have a link:

```
<a href="#">Click Here for Mobile</a>
```

I want to make it such that when the user clicks on the "Click Here For Mobile" link, I can take the user to:

```
www.mysite.com/root/mobile/#/?page=orderpage
```

Notice that the URL is similar to what it was before (preserving whatever parameters were there), except there is a "mobile" in between the root and the #.

How do I make it such that the  "Click Here For Mobile" link will have the redirect to the appropriate URL as described above?
Is it good practice to do this? Examples appreciated.

Comment: You want to reload the page or just client side routing ??

Comment: I only know of page reload to get to www.mysite.com/root/mobile/#/?page=orderpage. If client side routing is an option, that is okay too (i think).

Comment: client side routing will not work because you are changing the url before hash so you can do full page reload using <a target="_self" href="/root/mobile/#/?page=orderpage">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ajay said, client-side routing will not be possible in this case.

So what you're left with is either doing (like Ajay said):

```
<a target="_self" href="/root/mobile/#/?page=orderpage">
```

Or, you could define a function (in a service, in the specified controller, or someplace else where you have access to it) that takes a string and changes the $window.location.href (this will result in a page reload).

Something like this:

```
app.controller("SomeCtrl", function ($scope, $location, $window) {
    $scope.changeUrl = function (url) {
      var newUrl = $location.$$absUrl.replace("/#/", url);
      $window.location.href = newUrl;
    };
});
```

And then in your html you would use:

```
<a href="" ng-click="changeUrl('/mobile/#/')">Go mobile</a>
```

Without Javascript enabled (which I'm assuming you're not gonna be supporting with an Angular app) this would not take you anywhere. In that case, Ajay's solution is definately the prefered one.

The benefit of turning it into a function is that all you have to pass is what you're changing before the "/#/".

Good luck :)